# Charts en C# y solapamiento

Tags: c#, charts

Tengo dos "charts" con información (y algunas etiquetas a su lado) y están juntos. He programado un "mouse_hover" para que cuando el mouse pase por uno de ellos cambie su tamaño, funciona bien y lo hace de tal manera que se solapa con "chart" vecino y algunas etiquetas. La información que contiene el chart que amplia su tamaño queda debajo del chart que mantiene su tamaño y las etiquetas.

Necesito que pase lo contrario, que el chart que amplia su tamaño quedé sobre todas las etiquetas y otros gráficos. ¿Cómo lo hago? Espero haber explicado bien mi problama. Gracias por su ayuda.

Un saludo

Comment: Observo pocas visitas y ninguna respuesta. Mientras estaba (y estoy) investigando una solución, se me ocurrio una manera de evitar que mi Chart quede bajo otros Charts o Labels. Lo que hice fue poner estas gráficos/etiquetas en "invisible" mientras el cursor está en el Chart de interés. El trabajo fue sencillo, pero creo podría haber algo mas óptimo.

Comment: Cuando el mouse sale del Chart de interés, vuelo a visibilizar los Charts que no aparecían. Espero que sirva de referencia a los que necesiten hacer algo similar.